# SVM training for binary classifier always give class 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I'm making a banana detector project with `SVM classifier`. I have `358` image samples for the training and doing train-test-split with `test-size=0.2`, `random_state=42`.

Here is how my dataset look alike:
[image: Dataset]

I have labeled each image with `0` or `1` as the filename `postfix`. But, the `classification_report(...)` always return:

```
Accuracy: 0.7352941176470589
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.74      1.00      0.85        50
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        18

    accuracy                           0.74        68
   macro avg       0.37      0.50      0.42        68
weighted avg       0.54      0.74      0.62        68
```

The class `1` always have `0.00` in the table summary.

My full source code:

```
import os
import zipfile
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import cv2

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("dataset.zip", "r")
zip_ref.extractall()
zip_ref.close()

path = "bananas_dataset"
img_files = [(os.path.join(root, name))
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
    for name in files if name.endswith((".jpg"))]

winSize = (32, 32)
blockSize = (16, 16)
blockStride = (8, 8)
cellSize = (8, 8)
nbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = -1.
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 0.2
gammaCorrection = 1
nlevels = 64
useSignedGradients = True

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize, blockSize, blockStride,
    cellSize, nbins, derivAperture, winSigma, histogramNormType,
    L2HysThreshold, gammaCorrection, nlevels, useSignedGradients)

features = np.zeros((1, 324), np.float32)
labels = np.zeros(1, np.int64)
for i in img_files:
    img = cv2.imread(i)
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img, winSize)
    descriptor = np.transpose(hog.compute(resized_img))
    features = np.vstack((features, descriptor))
    labels = np.vstack((labels, int(i[-5])))

features = np.delete(features, (0), axis=0)
labels = np.delete(labels, (0), axis=0).ravel()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features,
                                                    labels,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=42)
print("X_train: {}, y_train: {}".format(X_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print("X_test: {}, y_test: {}".format(X_test.shape, y_test.shape))

clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))

print("Classification report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
joblib.dump(clf, "banana_hog_svm_clf.pkl")
```

This caused my prediction process always return class `0` as the result. Why this happened?

Comment: I think SVM is not recommended for this kind of tasks. Usually in computer vision problems you need convolutional neural networks (to extract feature).

Comment: I adapted https://github.com/lmzh123/ships_detection approach, because it has a similar task with mine. It works with SVM.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to an imbalance in the labels. For example, if 10% of your labels are to class 1 and 90% labels are class2, SVM will make a model with 90% accuracy where everything is being predicted as class2.

It will help if you check the distribution of your classes' labels.

Comment: But, in the https://github.com/lmzh123/ships_detection example, it has 3,600 samples where 2,900 is for class 2 and 700 is for class 1. It is an imbalance too.

Comment: So what is the performance? I do not see any results reported on that page. Any reason you 100% rely on what that GitHub page does? Is it a very famous code package?

Comment: The accuracy is pretty good, around 94%. The classification report is balance between class 0 and 1 too.

Comment: When it is an imbalanced dataset, the accuracy is always good, since we usually have a dominated class. That is the reason we should wether check the minority class misclassifications rate or use other measures like F1